# Calling a function from a set variable?

Tags: python

Im writing a python script and what I would like to do is capture the input into a variable and then use that to call a function with that name. Here is an example:

```
def test():
    print "You want to do a test!"

option = raw_input("What do you want to do? ") #User types in test
option()
```

Now this isnt working since python is not seeing option as a variable but rather is trying to call the function "option". What is the bast way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval()` will work, but as @MattDMo said it can be dangerous.

A much safer way to do this, if your functions are module globals:

```
globals()[option]()
```

`globals()` is a dictionary mapping strings to the module global objects those strings are bound to.  So `globals()[option]` looks up the string bound to `option` in that dict, and returns the object; e.g., `globals["test"]` returns the function object for `test()`.  Then adding `()` at the end calls that function object.  Bingo - you're done.

Comment: very good, I'd forgotten about that...

Comment: Awesome! I think thats a winner! Now all I need is to figure out functions that take multiple inputs and a catch all but I think I can do that with a try/except. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to be very careful about running arbitrary code, but if you absolutely need to, you can use the [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function.

What might be a better way is to give your user a menu of options, then do testing on the contents of `option` to see which one they picked, **then** run that function.

Comment: Hm, interesting. So what we are trying to do is to basically have an interactive shell and based on what the user inputs a function will run based on the input. So if the user types ls it will run a function that lists files from an api. Right now we have 

    if input == "ls":
        do funtion

I would like to have it so I can just add a new function without having a massive amount of if statements. I was just wondering if anyone had a simpler idea.

Comment: you don't need a huge amount of if statements, you can always store the function names in a list, then do `if option in list: ... `

Comment: I like that, thats a good idea. I like Tim Peters too though. I think it will work well, the only thing left is to figure out a catch all (if the command isnt found as a function) and ones with multiple optins (?,h,help all point to a function) but that may be easily done with a try/except. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `eval`.

From the help page, eval evaluates the source in the context of globals and locals. The source may be a string representing a Python expression or a code object as returned by compile().

For example:

```
 def a():
     print "Hello"

 inp = raw_input()
 eval(inp + "()")
```

On entering `a` at the stdin, the function `a` will be executed. Note that this could be dangerous without any safety checks.

Answer (score 0):

This is, I suppose, an actual use for bare `input`:

```
option = input("What do you want to do? ") #User types in test
option()
```

This is semantically equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.  Note that in python 3, `raw_input` becomes `input` so you will explicitly have to `eval` it.

The usual caveats of this type of operation being incredibly unsafe apply.  But I think that's obvious from your requirement of giving the user access to run arbitrary code, so...

Answer (score 0):

I like using a dict in situations like this.  You can even specify a default option if the user provides an answer that isn't expected.

```
def buy_it():
    print "use it"

def break_it():
    print "fix it"

def default():
    print "technologic " * 4

menu = {"buy it": buy_it, "break it": break_it}
option = raw_input("What do you want to do? ")
menu.get(option, default)()
```